# What could be causing this long waiting time on page load?

Tags: javascript, page-speed

What could be causing a 1.18s wait time when my page loads?
Just to make sure I did not have any conflicting or parallel scripts loading, I completely deleted all the script on my home page and ran the speed test again. Although I had a blank website and 5kb file size, there was still a 900ms "waiting" time.

I'm wondering if it could be my server? Any other thoughts or suggestions as it doesn't seem to be scripts.

[image: website load]

EDIT - Just ran a DNS test on pingdom and here are my results. Does this tell me anything? No nameservers found at child?

[image]

Comment: See this: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/46780/what-are-reasons-of-latency-for-a-http-request-to-load-html

Comment: +1 for list. Just ran Pingdom test and results above. what does this tell me?

Comment: Sounds like your the DNS zone is missing nameserver records on the child-side. I'd contact your DNS provider (e.g., domain registrar, web host provider, or third-party DNS service) for help.

Comment: You can run these two DNS health checks for more info too: http://dns-health.com/ and http://www.intodns.com/. Another good tool to use is the DNS check here: http://network-tools.com/

Comment: dan- I called hostgator and they didnt know what child-side NS records are.

Comment: See the error's explanation [here](http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/troubleshooting.php) (that was child-side DNS zone, not name servers). If you let me know the domain (you can delete the comment afterwards), I'll have a look at it for you.

Comment: I'm not seeing any nameserver issues with my internal tools or online tools. I'll post results for this in a second comment that I'll delete after 10 minutes...

Comment: I did another test at Pingdom and am getting a PTR record error for your second nameserver (ns2.___.com). Is HostGator providing your DNS for you (and not your domain registrar)?

Comment: No problem. It seems like there's an intermittent problem, but I can't view the DNS table. You might start another question for that with a screenshot of it. Good luck!

Comment: In chrome you can see how long each file take. This could help you out.

Answer (score 3):

Typically according to my understanding of HTTP:

- The Sending time is when the request headers are being upload to the server
- The Waiting time is when the request is being processed by the server and before the response begins to download
- The Receiving time is the time taken to download the response

My question would be does this happen for all of your pages? If so then I would assume that you don't have enough processing power on your server.

If it is only on one page, take a look at your code for that page and see if there is any part of it that could be taking a long time.

The last option could be your network speed, I think.

Comment: most pages are the same. one page is about 30% less. As I said in my post, I removed my all the script and still got a long page load time. I'm on with server admin now. will post results.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. To solve it, I installed W3 Total Cache and also used Cloudflare.  Now there is no issue at my website.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue today with a server wait period as extremely long as 14.5s, trust me! Pingdom and Uptrender just shown as your post depicted without any hint on why server has been really waiting for. And in my case it was "Backend Duration". After too much of research, i found this from GTMetrix test report's Timing Chart tab where it clearly shown the transition and associated delay upon every stage of HTTP request. With this clue i did further investigation and found a legacy plugins code giving a hit to mysql DB which abnormally taking 14.5s to get response back; till then the server keeps waiting! So I just fixed code and my home page rendered amazingly in less than 1.9s which earlier took around 16.3s which was really horrible! I still didn't fix any of render blocks, minifications, gzips, image optimise, etc without any such i'm getting very good speed; as Bankend duration as come down from 14.5s to 0.6s! I hope this information would be certainly helpful in a way or other for many developers facing this issue and so just dropping these few lines, Thx.